# How to Update Cookie Value in Angular js (or) JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

I am Struck in Updating Cookie Value.Here I am using Angular js for scription.
and here i need to update existing cookie, but i can't able update that one.

here is my code, Please any one review and suggest me.

```
$.ajax({
    type : "POST",
    url : appUrl + "/Login",
    data : {
        username : user,
        password : pwd,
        page : "home"
    },
    dataType : 'json',
    success : function(obj) {
        if (obj.direction != "") {
            var myAry = obj.LoginUserDetails[0];
            //alert("The json array is---->>>"+myAry.partnerid);
            setCookie('LoginDetails', JSON.stringify(myAry));
```

And After some operation i get the cookie like this

```
var storedAry = JSON.parse(getCookie('LoginDetails'));
```

and perform some operations

```
.ajax({
 url : appUrl+ '/EditPartner',
data : data1,                                                                                        
cache : false,                                                          
contentType : false,
processData : false,                                                                                                                                       
type : 'POST',                                                  
success : function(data) {                                                  
var txt = data;                                                 
var obj = eval('('+ txt + ')');                                                 

loginuserdetails = obj.allregdetails[0];// setCookie('LoginDetails',
```

After using this cookie now i want to update my cookie, for that i followed following procedure

```
setCookie('LoginDetails', JSON.stringify(myAry));//but not succedd so try below code


document.cookie = "LoginDetails"+ "="+ escape(JSON.stringify(loginuserdetails));
```

And after that i tested by getting that cokkie value but not updated

```
var logindetailsvalues = JSON.parse(getCookie('LoginDetails'));                                                             
console.log("details after updation---->>"+ getCookie('LoginDetails'));
```

Comment: Any reason why you were not using Angular driven POST and GET?
And Angular cookies?

Answer (score 0):

For angular use angular cookies  file ($cookieStore) http://jsfiddle.net/krimple/9dSb2/

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngCookies']);

myApp.controller('CookieCtrl', function ($scope, $rootScope, $cookieStore) {
    $scope.bump = function () {
        var lastVal = $cookieStore.get('lastValue');
        if (!lastVal) {
            $rootScope.lastVal = 1;
        } else {
            $rootScope.lastVal = lastVal + 1;
        }
        $cookieStore.put('lastValue', $rootScope.lastVal);
    }
});

myApp.controller('ShowerCtrl', function () {
});
```

other example

```
<script>
    angular.module('myApp', ['ngCookies']);
    function CookieCtrl($scope, $cookieStore) {
    $scope.lastVal = $cookieStore.get('tab');

    $scope.changeTab = function(tabName){
        $scope.lastVal = tabName;
        $cookieStore.put('tab', tabName);
    };
    }
</script>
```

**For Jquery**

use https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie
example code

```
$.cookie('the_cookie', 'the_value', { expires: 7 });
$.cookie('the_cookie', 'the_value', { expires: 7, path: '/' });
$.cookie('the_cookie'); // reading => "the_value" 
$.removeCookie('the_cookie');
```

Comment: Thnakyou Gaurav for Your valuable suggetion, here the problem coming from we are updation cookie with large size data like base64 image, we stopped that and now updated remaining data well.